# Extract value from jQuery Slider/Input to use globally without relying on console logging

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to be able to use the values that I get from my sliders here in more than just one action for some later calculation. In addition to the solution below, I tried declaring space as a variable before I excecute the jQuery function, but that didn't work either. I have the following code:

```js
$("#spaceRange").on("input", function () {
        space = Number($(this).val());
        leftEar.x(space * scale + faceDist);
        rightEar.x(-(space * scale + faceDist));
        updateObjects();
        return space;
    });

var num = $("#spaceInput").val();
    console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
    <label for="rightLeftSlider" class="form-label">R/L Space - Inches</label>
    <form>
        <input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="spaceRange" min="0" max="20" value="0"
            oninput="this.form.spaceInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" id="spaceInput" min="0" max="20" value="0"
            oninput="this.form.spaceRange.value=this.value" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are mixing Jquery, and regular HTML/js, eq `oninput`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event 
Unless it's mandatory, i would higly recommend to take out Jquery, and simply use regular JavaScript, at least for learning.

Comment: @NVRM this is just a small snippet. I use jquery in the rest of the project, it def needs to stay

Comment: If you want to use the value elsewhere, just refer to `$("#spaceInput").val();` in those functions.

Comment: @imvain2 this didn't work. console log returns the original value of the input box even after it has been changed. does not update, can't use in my math later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure on your direction here but this might get you started on how to pass variables around.

```js
// faked these since they were undefined
var leftEar = {
  x: function(v) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(v);
  }
};
var rightEar = {
  x: function(v) {
    console.log(v);
  }
};

function updateObjects(val) {
  // more fake of undefined stuff
  let scale = 1;
  let faceDist = 1;
  let space = val;
  leftEar.x(space * scale + faceDist);
  rightEar.x(-(space * scale + faceDist));
}

$("#spaceRange").on("input", function() {
  let v = $(this).val() * 1; //simpler than Number()
  $("#spaceInput").val(v);
  updateObjects(v);
});
$("#spaceInput").on("input", function() {
  let v = $(this).val() * 1; //simpler than Number();
  $("#spaceRange").val(v);
  updateObjects(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <label for="rightLeftSlider" class="form-label">R/L Space - Inches</label>
  <form>
    <input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="spaceRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" />
    <input type="number" id="spaceInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" o/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to put references to them in some sort of function that is triggered and called after they have been changed.

Having variables just floating in your code that load when the page loads isn't storing the values of the fields after they have been changed. It's storing the values at that point in time.

Here is an example that shows the values inside of a function, in this case just a click handler on a random button. Also I have a reference just floating outside that loads when the page loads.

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  console.log("I loaded after clicking the button so I got the current value  " + $("#spaceRange").val())
});

console.log("i Loaded with the page " + $("#spaceRange").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <label for="rightLeftSlider" class="form-label">R/L Space - Inches</label>
  <form>
    <input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="spaceRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.spaceInput.value=this.value" />
    <input type="number" id="spaceInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.spaceRange.value=this.value" />
  </form>
</div>


<button class="btn">Get Values</button>
```

Comment: took liberty to hit the "tidy" on your snippet